# polyline blinking in google-map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polyline

can anyone please tell me how to make the polyline to continuously blink .
I've drawn a polyline in google-map, but i could'nt make then blink.

**http://jsfiddle.net/wLeBh/8/**

My javascript code is as given below.

```
function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(10.012552, 76.327043);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: center,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
        },
        navigationControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var polylineCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.013566, 76.331549),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.013566, 76.331463),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.013503, 76.331313),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.013482, 76.331205),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.013419, 76.330926),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.013334, 76.330712),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.013313, 76.330411),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.013292, 76.330175),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.013228, 76.329854),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.013144, 76.329553),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.013059, 76.329296),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.012996, 76.329017),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.012869, 76.328802),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.012785, 76.328545),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.012700, 76.328223),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.012679, 76.328030),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.012658, 76.327837),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.012637, 76.327600),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.012573, 76.327322),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.012552, 76.327043),

    ];
    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: polylineCoordinates,
        strokeColor: '#FF3300',
        strokeOpacity: 2.0,
        strokeWeight: 5,
        editable: false
    });

    polyline.setMap(map);
    var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png");
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: polylineCoordinates[polylineCoordinates.length - 1],
        icon: icon,
        map: map,
        clickable: false
    });

}



initialize();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var map = null;      // and remove "var" from in front of the declaration in the initialize function
var polyline = null; // and remove "var" from in front of the declaration in the initialize function
function togglePolyline() {
  if (polyline.getMap() == null) { 
    polyline.setMap(map); }
  else {
    polyline.setMap(null); }
}

setInterval(togglePolyline, 1000);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SYEY4/1/)